# How to stop config file from throwing errors because of symbols?

Tags: c#, config

I have a config file with a value of symbols. This causes my compiler to throw an error (Illegal characters). My question is how can I keep my value with all its symbols without any errors:

```
<add key ="GroupValexA2" value ="<@&G65a6aas&>"/>
```

I tried using the \, but this did not work.

Comment: @John What about the @ symbol.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You will need to encode it

Comment: @John  Would this be correct: "&lt@&ampG65a6aas&amp&gt"/> ?

Comment: `&lt;@&amp;G65a6aas&amp;&gt;` maybe

Comment: No, it's not correct. You're missing the semicolons that end the escapes.

Comment: Please, change your config file with this: `<add key ="GroupValexA2" value ="&lt;@&amp;G65a6aas&amp;&gt;"/>`

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you guys so much!!!!

Comment: @JabbaaAAA, please, give me vote feedback, thanks too.

Comment: @AntonioLeonardo yeah we have all been there, but dont ask for votes, they are not needed (you will earn plenty), and its a little stalkerish and desperate

Comment: @TheGeneral, thanks for feed-back. In Sharepoint.stackexchange.com have some Microsoft Engineers answer questions and ask votes too. Please, if possible, give them same feedback? Because I see nobody I've this feedback for them. I think you, with your reputation it's more stronger option to them. What do you think?